# Apple Mach-O Linker Error while Archiving Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am getting the error while archiving the project, I googled it for the exact solution but they doesn't meet my requirements.

> Apple Mach-O Linker Error Command/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Some of the solution which I got,

- Import  the file `#import “xView.m` instead of `#import “xView.h`
- Cleaning the build and restart the xcode
- Missing of frame work

But it doesn't worked for me, even my project running while testing it in simulator.

Comment: I doubt this is the only error you get. What other warnings/errors your build log has?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081211/294884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved my issue , actually in my project i have two images which have the same name generally xcode not accept the same name of file but some where it accepted and due to this i am getting the error every time while archiving the project , so i removed the duplicate image and archive the project sucessfully.

hope this will help you guys .

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs when some file is missing in the build files. Check if you have remove some class file & its entry still exist in project file.

You can see it in build settings. Hope it'll resolve your issue.

If still not solved, ping the total description below the exception as found in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

There are many fixes but what was my problem was that I did not need a framework anymore, and I removed it but in one of my files it declared the framework at the top still and used that framework. Deleted it and it worked! Plus check if you have not messed anything up in your AppDelegate.m