# linker command failed when archive

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, linker

I want to **archive** a React Native project user the latest Xcode and always failed because linker command failed.

When I run `xcodebuild -verbose` & `Ld` command, then the error is like this

```
ld: file not found: build/xxxxx_app.build/Release-iphoneos/xxxxx_app.build/Objects-normal/armv7/xxxxx_app`
```

[image: Error screenshot]

I had tried the bellow steps, but still the same error appears

- Remove Pods & install them again
- Run clean under menu Product , empty build & DerivedData folder
- Change Build Active Architecture Only to Yes
- Remove linked Frameworks and Libraries and re-add them

Some configuration

[image: Linked Frameworks and Libraries]

So what is the right way to archive ios project?

Comment: Have you find a solution?

Comment: what version of react-native are you using?

Answer (score 1):

try this, go to Target -> Build Settings,then search these three as following,

GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS,

CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION,

CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE,

set NO to each value then clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

please remove all derived data
step1: cmd + option + shift + k
step2: cmd + shift + k
step3: restart xcode

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the magical fix

## Build settings, Enable Bitcode -> NO